# about matrix manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, linear-algebra

I have a large matrix and I want to extract different sub-matrices that actually have elements on different positions. Using `Extract` and mention the position of every element is quiet tedious and will take too much time to type.

What command can I use to extract the required elements? For example I want to extract 2*2 matrix with these elements

```
{{[[1, 1]], [[1, 9]]}, {[[9, 1]], [[9, 9]}}
```

Is there another way where I don't have to specify the position of the elements repeatedly?

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: What do you mean by nested `[...]`s in nested `{...}`s? As far as I know, it does not make sense in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Do you just want to identify where non zero elements are?

Comment: not actually, but my purpose is to just extract  different submatrix repeatdly from a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then for this type of problem, you can use the following shorter notation. I use a random matrix `m` as a test:

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {10, 10}];
m[[{1, 9}, {1, 9}]]

(* {{8, 6}, {3, 9}} *)
```

This should be the same as specifying it manually

```
{{m[[1, 1]], m[[1, 9]]}, {m[[9, 1]], m[[9, 9]]}}
(* {{8, 6}, {3, 9}} *)
```

Comment: sirr it is goood but what i doo if i have such type of code[{{Q[[1, 1]], Q[[1, 7]], Q[[1, 6]], Q[[1, 9]], Q[[1, 15]], 
   Q[[1, 14]]}, {Q[[7, 1]], Q[[7, 7]], Q[[7, 6]], Q[[7, 9]], 
   Q[[7, 15]], Q[[7, 14]]}, {Q[[6, 1]], Q[[6, 7]], Q[[6, 6]], 
   Q[[6, 9]], Q[[6, 15]], Q[[6, 14]]}, {Q[[9, 1]], Q[[9, 7]], 
   Q[[9, 6]], Q[[9, 9]], Q[[9, 15]], Q[[9, 14]]}, {Q[[15, 1]], 
   Q[[15, 7]], Q[[15, 6]], Q[[15, 9]], Q[[15, 15]], 
   Q[[15, 14]]}, {Q[[14, 1]], Q[[14, 7]], Q[[14, 6]], Q[[14, 9]], 
   Q[[14, 15]], Q[[14, 14]]}}] how it can be simplify???

Comment: sirr any short program that will be helpfull for such coding